# How can I transform a list in multiple dataframes in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix

I have a list of multiple matrices. I can transform an item of this list into a dataframe using this code:

```
as.data.frame(list_of_matrices[i])
```

But how can I do the same in an automatic way for all indexes (i)?

I tried:

```
a <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(list_of_matrices)){
  dataframes[i] <- as.data.frame(list_of_matrices[i])
}
```

but it didn't work:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(X1 = 1:102, X2 = c(2L,  : 
  replacement has 102 rows, data has 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OP's code, we need `[[` instead of `[` because by doing `[`, it will still be a `list` of length 1

```
for(i in seq_along(list_of_matrices)){
    list_of_matrices[[i]] <- as.data.frame(list_of_matrices[[i]])
  }
```

If we need multiple objects in the global env, (not recommended), either `assign` or `list2env` should work.  After naming the `list` with custom names or `letters` (a, b, c, ,..), use `list2env`

```
names(list_of_matrices) <- letters[seq_along(list_of_matrices)]
list2env(list_of_matrices, .GlobalEnv)
```

Now, we check for

```
head(a)
head(b)
```

---

Another option is `assign with in the loop itself

```
for(i in seq_along(list_of_matrices)) {
    assign(letters[i], as.data.frame(list_of_matrices[[i]])
 }

head(a)
head(b)
```

NOTE: We assume that the length of `list_of_matrices` is less than 26 or else have to change the names from the built-in `letters` to something else..

Comment: But it became a list of dataframes. I'd like to output multiple dataframes (not in a list). I don't know if it's possible. Thanks!

Comment: @AntonioCosta I would advise not to do that because it creates a lot of objects in the global env.  What would be the name of those datasets

Comment: I tried to use your solution but after using your first script I get the following error message : "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Example list of matrices
mat_list <- list(
  matrix(runif(20), 4, 5),
  matrix(runif(20), 4, 5)
)
# Convert to list of df
df_list <- lapply(mat_list, as.data.frame)
```

Comment: But df_list is stiil a list of dataframes

Comment: Maybe I got the question wrong. What is the desired output? As far Is I understand the question and the code you want to convert your list of matrices to a list of dataframe.

Comment: If I put " as.data.frame(list_of_matrices[i]) ", I can convert that index of the list into a dataframe. But I want to do it for all indexes. No need to type as.data.frame(list_of_matrices[1]), as.data.frame(list_of_matrices[2])...thank you!!!

Comment: That`s what `lapply` is doing. It converts each matrix in your list to a dataframe. It's in some sense just a shorthand for a for-loop. Result is the same.